# Run Visual Studio as Admin using batch script with \runas

Tags: windows, batch, visual-studio-2017

Executables can be run as admin using a batch script with a command like

```
runas /savecred /user:admin "C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe"
```

when being logged in as a non-admin user.

Why is this not possible with the Visual Studio 2017 executable?

The command prompt asks me to fill in the password and starts Visual Studio, but it is not run as admin (compare `right click on .exe file -> Run as admin`).

How can I achieve this behaviour with a batch script?

Comment: Your command works fine for me using 2019 (I don't have 2017 installed).  What exe are you running?

Comment: `RunAs` *does not* elevate.

Comment: @user1292580 but it does seem to elevate ``cmd.exe`` for me - that is, after I fill in the password, it will start cmd as admin.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas ``... Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe`` is the executable I'm trying to run.

Comment: One thing I *can* tell you is that running VS as an admin is generally a bad idea and there are very few cases for it since like 2003.  I have had code that needed it to be so.. but those cases can *usually* (not always) be worked around by adding said user permissions using GPEdit.msc or finding a better pattern.  Do you ***need*** the password cached?

Comment: Unfortunately, the build process of the application I'm working on requires VS to be run as admin. 

The password being cached would make life a bit easier but is not vital to the process. I was just wondering why it works with cmd.exe and *not* with VS 2017.